# How to manually instantiate a viewscoped bean multiple times

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm building a one page app with JSF that looks something like this :

[image: home page preview]

The menu on the left is dynamically generated and clicking on one of the submenu creates a tab in which I display content from an `<ui:include>`.
**Menu and tabs code :**

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" size="210">
    <h:form id="menu_form">
        <p:panelMenu style="width:200px" model="#{homeView.menu}" />
    </h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit id="center-layout" position="center">

    <p:tabView id="tabss" style="font-size: 15px"
        activeIndex="#{homeView.index}" scrollable="true">
        <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{homeView.onTabClose}"
            update="tabss" />
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{homeView.onTabChange}"
            update="tabss" />

        <c:forEach items="#{homeView.openTabs}" var="otab">
            <p:tab title="#{otab.title}" closable="true"
                style="font-size: 15px" rendered="#{otab.open}">
                <p:scrollPanel mode="native" styleClass="scrollPanels">
                    <ui:include src="#{otab.content}" />
                </p:scrollPanel>
            </p:tab>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:tabView>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

**Backing bean for the home page :**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class HomeView {

    private List<Tab> tabs;
    private List<Tab> openTabs;
    private int index;
    private TabService tabService;
    private MenuService menuService;
    private MenuModel menu;
    @ManagedProperty("#{loginView}")
    private LoginView loginView;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tabService = new TabService();
        menuService = new MenuService();
        tabs = menuService.loadTabs(loginView.getUtilisateur().getProfile());
        openTabs = new ArrayList<Tab>();
        menu = menuService.loadMenu(loginView.getUtilisateur().getProfile());
    }

    public void addTab(String title) {
        if (tabService.check(openTabs, title)) {
            openTabs = tabService.addTab(tabs, openTabs, title);
        }
        if (tabService.getIndex(openTabs, title) != -1) {
            index = tabService.getIndex(openTabs, title);
        }
    }

    public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {
        String title = event.getTab().getTitle();
        String ti = openTabs.get(index).getTitle();
        openTabs = tabService.closeTab(openTabs, title);
        if (ti.equals(title)) {
            index = tabService.setIndex(index);
        } else {
            index = tabService.setIndex(openTabs, ti);
        }
    }

    public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        index = tabService.getIndex(openTabs, event.getTab().getTitle());
    }
    // Getters and setters
```

I should note that clicking on the submenus calls the methode `addTab(Title)` to open the tab
Each of the included page (the one displayed in the tabs) uses its own viewscoped bean which is destroyed after closing the tab (see the above code).
**Problematic :**
In the above screenshot I showed a tab in which I display a search result in a `<p:dataTable>`, the behavior I want is :
Whenever an element is selected from the dataTable, I want to open a Tab where I will display more info about the said element. What is important to me is being able to open more than one Tab(that displays more info about an element) at the same time.
What I have in mind is creating an xhtml which will do the displaying part, and a viewscoped bean to back the said page. So is there a way to manually instantiate the said bean (everytime the user clicks on the button) and then populate it with the corresponding data, that way I can re-use the same page multiple times ?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the element info page to be viewscoped as its just an info display page ? You can make it requestscoped unless you have the need for viewscope ?

Comment: @OTM well technically it's not just displaying info, what I want to do in that page is : execute some queries using the selected item to fetch the data for displaying (this will go in its init() method) and it will have some command buttons which will execute some more queries.
Making it requestScoped will allow it to be instantiated multiple times ?

Comment: Yes, with requestscoped bean it will be  instanciated multiple times, to be specific one instanciation per each request for info page. Even if you have command buttons in info page the further submits should work with requestscoped as long as you maintain data in request scope.

Comment: I've tried it but just changing tabs counts as a request  and triggers the destruction of the bean. Because in my case I want to keep the bean alive until I close the tab (as I mentionned in my question)

Comment: Ok. If you want to use the same view multiple times, i dont think you can have multiple viewscoped instances of the same bean. As a workaround you could have the same viewscoped bean for multiple info page requests. When you open an info page you can pass an identifier. For eg., 1,2 for info page one and two respectives and store any associated data in a collection by the identifier and do the varible binding in the page accordingly.

Comment: @OTM I've done some testing with what you suggested and it seems to work for me so far, Thank you. Can you put it as answer so that I can accept it ?
PS: I've found somewhere that you can instantiate a bean multiple times but you need to know the number of instances beforehand adn you need to specify their names in faces-config.xml :/

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I have updated it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could have the same viewscoped bean for multiple info page requests. When you open an info page you can pass an identifier as a parameter. For eg., 1,2 for info page one and two respectively and store any associated data in a collection by the identifier and do the variable binding in the page accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you want to do, one possibility is to evaluate an expression with the view scoped bean, programatically:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
ValueExpression vex = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{viewBeanName}", ViewBeanClass.class);
ViewBeanClass viewBean = (ViewBeanClass) vex.getValue(elContext);
```

That is going to instantiate the bean if it doesn't exists, if it does exist, it will return it.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand it very well. I want to instantiate the same bean multiple (each time the user selects an item from the dataTable).

Comment: Ok, I have done that before passing a parameter to the include:
<ui:param name = "bean" value = "#{searchResult[index]}" />
And in included html you use the #{bean} variable. I hope this helps

Comment: The problem I have is not about how to pass a parameter to the include, but rather I want to open the same page multiple times but each time with a different parameter

Comment: But using paremeter you can pass whatever you want to the same xhtml, just use an array in the parameter or something to iterate over:
<ui:param name = "bean" value = "#{searchResult[index]}" />

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I've already solved it using @OTM suggestion (check the comments on the original question)